# Drag n Drop - Android

Tags: android, drag-n-drop

Eu fiz um sistema de Drag n Drop, mas quando eu insiro o item, parece que a gravidade está como top, ao inserir novos, eles ficam em cima uns dos outros, como fazer o drop onde eu solto o dedo?

Os itens estão em uma ListView, eu os obtenho assim:

```
public void criarListagem(List<croquiA> cro) {
        CroquiAdapter adapter = new CroquiAdapter(cro, this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setDivider(null);

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
            arrayClass.p = arrayClass.pistasIds[position];
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("simple_text", "text");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            newClick(arrayClass.p, l);

            if(l != 0){
                findViewById(R.id.container).setOnDragListener(new MyOnDragListener());
            }

            return false;
        });
```

MyOnDragListener:

```
class MyOnDragListener implements View.OnDragListener{

        public MyOnDragListener(){
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();

            switch (action){
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                   if(event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)){
                       return true;
                   }else{
                       return false;
                   }

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v;

                    // Aqui eu copio a view e adiciono um ImageView
                    // em vez de remover, porque como é um adaptador, então é
                    // não é possível removê-lo

                    ImageView oldView = (ImageView) view;
                    ImageView newView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

                    newView.setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) oldView.getDrawable()).getBitmap());

                    container.addView(newView);

                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    break;

            }

            return true;
        }
```

Quando faço o drop os itens ficam assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que as imagens vão se amontoando.

Comment: Quer que fiquem duas imagens ou apenas uma?

Comment: @ramaral quero que quando eu for adicionando, adicione uma cópia e essa seja criada onde eu soltei o dedo, tipo, soltei no meio da tela, o ImageView seja criado lá, porque do jeito que está, quando solto ele ficam lá no topo e vão se amontoando :3

Comment: @ramaral e se possível, que essa cópia da imagem adicionada, fosse também possível fazer o drag n drop com ela

Comment: Não poderá usar um RelativeLayout. Use um [AbsoluteLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) ou uma *custom view*. Entretanto procure, pois pode haver algo já feito.

Comment: @ramaral rapaz, eu consegui, mas algo pronto nada, eu já revirei essa Internet inteira, não achei nada sobre

Comment: @ramaral pronto :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em meu MyOnDragListener, eu preciso especificar a posição de onde colocar a nova versão no meu layout. Fazendo assim:

```
 View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
 RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v;
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
 params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

ImageView oldView = (ImageView) view;
ImageView newView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
params.leftMargin = (int) event.getX() - oldView.getWidth()/2;
params.topMargin = (int) event.getY() - oldView.getHeight()/2;

container.addView(newView, params);
```

E para adicionar o drag n drop para a nova view, é só fazer:

```
newView.setOnLongClickListener(vi -> { 
ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("simple_text", "text"); 
View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(vi); 
vi.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, vi, 0); vi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
return true; 
});
```

[Resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49972178/drop-where-i-release-my-finger/49974819#49974819) de @Locdoc01

Comment: Eu pensei nessa possibilidade mas me pareceu que não iria funcionar em todas as situações, tal como eu entendi o que você pretendia.

Comment: @ramaral funcionou perfeitamente, mesmo estando dentro de um scrollView e um HorizontalScrollView